# convert .pem private key to .key format

Tags: openssl, certificate

i have a private key in .pem format. i wish to convert this into .key format. is there any way i can do that?

i am referring [to this guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/help/articles/sso-keygen?hl=fr) by google on how to generate certificates and private keys for SSO

i have generated the private key using openssl command:

```
openssl genrsa -out rsaprivkey.pem 1024
```

what can i do to get the private key in **.key** format?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no .key format. You can have private (or public) key in PEM or DER encoding. And you can have private key in PKCS#1 or PKCS#8 format. The extensions (.der, .pem, .key, .cer etc.) are only for convenience to easily identify what is inside (well, we wish to trust that the content corresponds to the extension used).

Command `openssl genrsa -out rsaprivkey.pem 1024` generated private key in PKCS#1 format and PEM encoding. In the guide you mentioned there are additional steps to take:

```
openssl rsa -in rsaprivkey.pem -pubout -outform DER -out rsapubkey.der
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in rsaprivkey.pem -out rsaprivkey.der -nocrypt
```

Step 1 extracts the public key from rsaprivkey.pem and encodes it in DER format. Step 2 transforms the private key from PKCS#1 to PKCS#8 format (unencrypted) and DER encoding.

The guide also mentions that some Java SSO example expects DSA keys. The keys that you generated using `openssl genrsa -out rsaprivkey.pem 1024` are RSA keys.

Comment: That's blatantly false. .key is a format and it's actually what openssl uses: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs Here's an actual answer from someone who knows what they're talking about OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874483/converting-binary-private-key-into-pem-format?rq=1

Comment: @AustinCapobianco I agree 100% with @pepo, there's no `.key` format, and `.key` is an ambiguous extension. There are PEM or DER encoding, which can both bundle keys and/or certificates and there's no official indication what extensions one should use. I tend to be specific about the encoding, so I prefer to use `.der` and `.pem` file extension, and the file name is more specific about what it holds, in the same way as @pepo